# how to load a folder given just a ServerRelativeUrl using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Tags: client-object-model, url, .net

In my application I have a url of a folder as retrieved by folder.ServerRelativeUrl() eg. `/consulting/TeamSiteTemplate/Documents/`

Now I want to get a list of folders inside this folder. I use this code:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
   folder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folder.ServerRelativeUrl);
   clientContext.Load(folder);
   clientContext.Load(folder.Folders);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

   foreach (Folder childFolder in folder.Folders)
   {
      // process folder
   }
}
```

This only seems to work when siteUrl contains the site eg. `http://sharepoint/consulting/TeamSiteTemplate` - but what if I don't know the site name of the given url? Or don't know if it has a subsite, etc.

So simply:

How can I get a site/subsite part from a relative url - or just the site if no subsite?

or: Is there another way to do this?

Comment: where is your code running? what type of app is it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wait for SP.js to load (which seems safe since your using CSOM), you should have a global variable named "**L_Menu_BaseUrl**" which will be the absolute url to the current site.

Between this, the folder's server relative url, and a little logic, you should be able to get what you need.

Comment: I am using the .net sharepoint libraries - not sure how I would get that global variable.